# PowerPivot Cohort Analysis

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm trying to do cohort analysis using Excel's PowerPivot. I have a table recording which users have purchased which products in which months eg.

UserID    Product    Date    Quantity
1           Ham     Mar 15     2
1           Cheese  Jan 15     7
2           Ham     Mar 15     8
3           Fish    Mar 15     2
2           Cheese  Apr 15     8

I want to use a calculated field to filter for a cohort of users who purchased a given product in a given month but be able to analyse all their purchases.

Eg cohort Ham, March 15

--> Users 1, 2

UserID    Product    Date    Quantity
1           Ham     Mar 15     2
1           Cheese  Jan 15     7
2           Ham     Mar 15     8
2           Cheese  Apr 15     8

I know this could be done easily using SQL but I am working with colleagues who prefer to use Excel over Access/Some SQL interface.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated column like this:

=if([UserID]&SlicerValue=[UserID]&[Product],[UserID])

where HAM would be selected from slicer created from a table of unique products.

Comment: Thank you, if I create slicers for product (and date), how do I reference them in the PowerPivot Table and prevent them from directly filtering my table?